# Cross domain iframe, between file:// and localhost://

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, cors, atom-editor

I am running atom on my machine and am trying to do drag and drop between atom and an iframe I have being served up by tomcat on my machine.  However I am running into CORS issues since the node server in atom has a `location.origin` of `file://` and my iframe is `http://localhost:8080`  how can I make it so that tomcat sets the location as `file://` or how can can proxy requests to a specific URL with it appearing as `file://`